# Manage complex select/deselect artis/album/song

Tags: javascript, arrays

First of all sorry for the vague title, but i didn’t know how to explain my problem in a better way.

Anyway this is what i want. Let’s say we have three tabs: one showing artist list, one showing album list and one showing songs. All this three tabs has selectable lists and i would like to be able, for example, to select and artist, then going to albums (that now should be show all as selected because i checked the artis) and be able to deselect one album and then, for, example, be able to go to songs and manage the songs individually.
Of course then i should be able to retrive the list of all the songs selected by the user.

**EDIT 1**
added two images to explain better

[image: page 1] [image: page 2]

**EDIT 2**
Added some code. At the moment i have only HTML and CSS, i'm waiting for your help for the JS code :)

that's the HTML structure

```
<div id="tabs" class="page-content tabs overflowTab">
<div id="tab1" class="tab active">
  <div class="content-block-title" id="indexScrollOffset">Seleziona artisti</div>
  <div class="list-block media-list">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="item-content.modificato">
          <div class="item-media modificato">
            <i class="icon icon-form-checkbox modificato"></i>
          </div>  
          <a href="#" class="item-link" id="apriTitoliLibro1">
            <div class="item-inner modificato">
              <div class="item-title-row">
                <div class="item-title">Artist 1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="item-subtitle">Some Text</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="item-content.modificato">
          <div class="item-media modificato">
            <i class="icon icon-form-checkbox modificato"></i>
          </div>  
          <a href="#" class="item-link" id="apriTitoliLibro2">
            <div class="item-inner modificato">
              <div class="item-title-row">
                <div class="item-title">Artist 2</div>
              </div>
              <div class="item-subtitle">Some Text</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      [...]  
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab">
  <div class="content-block-title">Seleziona Album</div>
  <div class="list-block media list">
    <div class="list-group">
      <ul>
        <li class="list-group-title">Artist 1</li>
        <li id="titoliLibro1">
          <div class="item-content-modificato titoli">
            <div class="item-media modificato fake-media-list">
              <i class="icon icon-form-checkbox modificato"></i>
            </div>  
            <a href="personalizzaArticoli.html" class="item-link">
              <div class="item-inner modificato titoli">
                <div class="item-title-row modificato">
                  <div class="item-title modificato">Album 1</div>
                  <div class="item-after modificato"><span class="font-size-artt-label">Some text</div>
                </div> 
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="item-content-modificato titoli">
            <div class="item-media modificato fake-media-list">
              <i class="icon icon-form-checkbox modificato"></i>
            </div>  
            <a href="personalizzaArticoli.html" class="item-link">
              <div class="item-inner modificato titoli">
                <div class="item-title-row modificato">
                  <div class="item-title modificato">Album 2</div>
                  <div class="item-after modificato"><span class="font-size-artt-label">Some text</div>
                </div> 
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        [...]
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tab">
  <div class="content-block-title">Seleziona song</div>
    <div class="list-block searchbar-not-found">
      <ul>
        <li class="item-content">
          <div class="item-inner">
            CONTENT HERE IS ADDED DYNAMICALLY FROM A WEBSQL DB
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit 3**
It's a phonegap application and yes, already using jQuery (as less as possibile for performance) :)

Now my question: which is the best way to handle this? My only idea is to create an array and update it with all the elements selected and, in order to show an element as selected or not, checking it with indexOf to see if it exist… is this a good way? I’m a bit worried about performance.

Thanks

Comment: Hard to answer, without seeing some code. HTML, JS, CSS...? anything to start from? Can you use jQuery? Do you want to operate on a JSON Object level or plain selecting with mouse events on DOM elements?

Comment: Added question with some more info, sorry :)